# PGFPLOTS: Insert a boxplot outside the chart axis labels, much like GNU R

Tags: pgfplots, labels, bar-chart

I have some code that plots a horizontal barchart. What I would like to do is put a boxplot or confidence interval above my horizontal axis which is on top of the chart. GNU R (see R In Action, Robert Kabacoff) allows boxplots along/out-side the horizontal/vertical axis which gives a nice look and much information at a glance.

In a similar manner, I was trying to add a boxplot or horizontal error bars above the x axis labels. Since the boxplot plots quartiles, error bars/confidence interval with the min/max about the mean may be more meaningful for what I'm showing. How do I get something like that? Is there some clipping going on, as my axis shift up seems to ignore larger shift values. Also, I can't get the vertical red line to extend above the x axis. My thought was to plot a thick red line of +/- n SDEV and thin error bars of min/max above the x axis and a boxplot on the bottom of the chart. With that I would like to label the \mu and +/- n\sigma points if possible.

I commented out the error bar addplot below. Another thought is how can I get PGFPLOTS to calculate the mean/sdev. If boxplot can calculate the quartiles, is there some mechanism to pull the data column Miles from the inline table?

I started this project keeping Tufte Principles in mind, but I keep adding more ink items. I hope to merge some other data into this type of chart. I really appreciate any help with this problem.
Regards, Dave

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,relsize}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=.95\textwidth, compat=newest} 

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/x axis shift down/.style={
    x axis line style={yshift=-#1},
    xtick style={yshift=-#1},
    xticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/y axis shift left/.style={
    y axis line style={xshift=-#1},
    ytick style={xshift=-#1},
    yticklabel shift={#1}}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Miles,   Bike,    rdate 
12.5,    Yel-11,  {$\stackrel{\hbox{Yel-11}}   {\hbox{\tiny 03/30/14}}$}
16.5,    Fuji,    {$\stackrel{\hbox{Fuji}}     {\hbox{\tiny 04/23/14}}$}
21.0,    8000SHX, {$\stackrel{\hbox{8000SHX}}  {\hbox{\tiny 05/18/14}}$}
24.2,    Yel-11,  {$\stackrel{\hbox{Yel-11}}   {\hbox{\tiny 05/24/14}}$}
\end{filecontents}
%                                    

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={semithick,tick style={major tick
length=4pt,thick,black}}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{ \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
width=0.90\linewidth,height=4cm,
xbar,/pgf/bar shift=0pt,
% title style={yshift=1cm},
% title={\centering More Customization: ``colorbar top''},
title={\centering label 2014},
title style={yshift=1cm, text width=8cm,font=\rmfamily\itshape\Large},
xmin=0, xmax=50, xticklabel pos=upper, tick align=outside,
xticklabel style={major tick length=20pt, color=black,tickwidth={10pt}},
axis x line*=top, %tickwidth={2pt},
axis y line*=left, y axis line style={opacity=0},
xmajorgrids, major grid style=white, axis on top,
xtick={0,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50}, %,100,150,200,250},
separate axis lines, x axis shift up=35pt, y axis shift left=10pt,
%xtick=\empty, %xlabel= {},
%enlarge x limits={value=0.1, upper},
enlarge y limits=0.25,
ytick={0,...,\numberofrows},
%ytick={0,...,\pgfmathresult}, %\pgfplotsretval},
y dir=reverse,
y tick label style={align=right, major tick length=5pt},
yticklabels from table={data.csv}{[index]2},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal,
%point meta=explicit symbolic
]

\addplot [draw,fill=blue, discard if not={Bike}{Fuji}] 
        table [y expr=\coordindex, x index=0, col sep=comma]{data.csv};

% \addplot [draw,fill=blue!60!white, discard if not={Bike}{Yfoil}] 
%         table [y expr=\coordindex, x index=0, col sep=comma]{data.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=yellow,  discard if not={Bike}{Yel-11}] 
        table [ y expr=\coordindex, x index=0,col sep=comma]{data.csv};

% \addplot [draw,fill=red,     discard if not={Bike}{Y-22}] 
%         table [ y expr=\coordindex, x index=0,col sep=comma]{data.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=gray,    discard if not={Bike}{8000SHX}] 
        table [ y expr=\coordindex, x index=0,col sep=comma]{data.csv};

\draw [red,dotted,thick] (axis cs:18.6,-1) -- (axis cs:18.6,29)
       node[anchor=west,on top] at (axis cs:19.0,0.5)
            {label}; 
\draw  node[anchor=center,on top] at (axis cs:40.0,3) {label};

%\addplot[error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x fixed=5.12,] coordinates{ (18.6,-1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  }%fbox
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've forgotten to add the definition of `x axis shift up` and `on top`. And yes, stuff outside the axis limits are clipped by default, try adding `clip=false` to the axis options.

Comment: Did the tricks of Torbørn T. help to solve your question so we can close it as being solved or do you need further assistance?